# How to use PyFFTW's wisom

Tags: python, fftw, pyfftw

I didn't see an actual example on pyfftw's documentation of how to use the 'wisdom' feature so I'm a little confused.

My code looks something like the following:

```
# first FFT
input = pyfftw.zeros_aligned(arraySize, dtype='complex64')
input[:] = image
fftwObj = pyfftw.builders.fft2(input, planner_effort='FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE')
imageFFT = fftwObj(input)

wisdom = pyfftw.export_wisdom()

pyfftw.import_wisdom(wisdom)

# second FFT with the same input size but different input
input = pyfftw.zeros_aligned(arraySize, dtype='complex64')
input[:] = image2
fftwObj = pyfftw.builders.fft2(input, planner_effort='FFTW_EXHAUSTIVE')
imageFFT2 = fftwObj(input)
```

The [docs](http://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#wisdom-functions) say that `export_wisdom` outputs a tuple of strings and that `import_wisdom` takes in this tuple as an argument.

When am I supposed to export the wisdom and am I supposed to save this tuple out to a file for each FFT?

When do I load it back in? Before the call to each FFT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, exporting and importing wisdom is a method to maintain state between sessions.

The wisdom is the knowledge about how best to plan an FFT. During a session, the internal "wisdom" is made up of all the plans that are made, and the wisdom that has been imported. Repeatedly importing the same wisdom file is not useful because that knowledge is already known after the first import.

You export wisdom when you want the knowledge about a particular transform plan to be used instead of having to work it out again. It need only plan for that transform once per session though.

Comment: Ok, so let's say I have two main transforms dealing with different size inputs (transform A and B). Both transforms are repeated several times, each time with the same sized matrix input but with different inputs. The way I'm currently doing it is exporting the wisdom to a file after the 1st Transform A call and after the 1st Transform B call. Then I load the wisdom if the file containing the wisdom exists. Is this the right way?

Comment: Uhm, you only need to load wisdom if you haven't yet done the transform yet this session and you want prior knowledge about how to do it available to FFTW. You never need to load a wisom file you've saved in the current session - you'll gain nothing. Wisdom is nothing more than the volatile internal (useful) FFTW state dumped out to string.

Comment: Yes I understand that. So if I don't want my session to spend any time planning, I should just write the wisdom out to a file and then import it correct?

Comment: Correct, though only once and certainly not before _every_ call.

Comment: Yup got it. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation says that one can use the flags 'FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY' along with any other flag to which the planner would switch if there is no wisdom for the particular transform. I used the following : flags=('FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY','FFTW_MEASURE', ) and yet get the error message : RuntimeError: No FFTW wisdom is known for this plan. What is the correct way to use the flags ?

Comment: @Sajid you need to load the wisdom first. As the docs say `This tells FFTW to raise an error if no plan for this transform and data type is already in the wisdom.`. The point is it will never try to plan, only using pre-planned wisdom. If that wisdom is not available because you haven't loaded it, it will error.

Comment: I did load the wisdom but since the plan for the transform was not in the wisdom, the error was raised. I took the passing of the second 'fftw_measure' flag to mean that if the fftw object does not find any relevant plan it should switch to this measure flag instead of raising an error. Is there a way that I can tell the fftw object to use wisdom if possible and fall back on fftw measure when the plan of interest is not present in the wisdom file ?

Comment: @Sajid that's its default behaviour. Just leave out the `FFTW_WISDOM_ONLY` flag.

Comment: @Henry Thank You!